# Parsing of project.pbxproj file

Tags: swift, parsing, xcode-project, xcodeproj

Is there any frameworks for parsing of `project.pbxproj` contained in `.xcodeproj` file?

Comment: What type of parsing do you want exactly?

Comment: I want to find and update build phase scripts

Answer (score 3):

Ruby: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj

Swift: https://github.com/xcodeswift/xcproj

Both parse the Xcodeproject file into a more manageable object.

Allowing you to add new files, remove build phrases or edit what files belong to a target

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I'm one of xcproj contributors :)